# Custom emails automatically generated based on participants filling in drupal forms

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, email, civirules, custom-templates

Hi to all and thanks in advance.

I'm on Drupal 7 and Civi 5.20.2. I have the CiviRules and EmailAPI (CiviCoOp) extensions as well as Mosaico. 
We have participants to our events that apply for funding (either travel, accomodation or both) through a Drupal (Civi Powered) form. 
I need to be able to send automated user tailored emails when they submit the form.

Like

Dear {user},
Thank you for aply for funding for {event title}. We are considering your {type_of_funding} application and we will get back to you sortly.
Kind regards...

I can get the event to triger through CiviRules and EmailAPI, but I cannot (or more correctly do not know) how to create an email template that can feed of the {xxx info xxx} when the specific rule runs, so the email is user specific and friendly.

Kind regards
Aris

Comment: is there a good reason not to have Drupal webforms do the sending? sounds like you would have the data you need for your tokens in the webform submission

Comment: Hi Petednz, we have a complex participant approval process that changes their status a number of times. That status may be triggered by changes through a Drupal form, but it may also be triggered by changes directly on their record in Civi (different teams use different interfaces). As such I am hoping to use CiviRules to do all the emailing from so I can have the conditions in one place...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of tokens you see when editing a template changes depending on where you're editing from.  Unfortunately, CiviRules doesn't expose event/participant/contribution tokens in the drop-down - but if you use them in the email, they WILL work.

To see the tokens you may want to use, create a new Scheduled Reminder (**Administer menu » Communications » Scheduled Reminders), and create a new reminder based on an event.  You should be able to see event etc. tokens (see screenshot below).  Then either save as a new template, or simply copy the tokens into an existing one.[image]

Comment: Hi Jon G, thank you for the reply. I did what you suugested. Created a "scheduled reminder" with the text I needed, inserted the event tokens and the copied the whole thing across...  Although hopeful, I think there is an issue if I try to copy the tokens to an email template, so it can be triggered by a CiviRule. I believe that the "process" does not know which event is being reference... and as such when the email is tiggered, I just get a blank space where the {event.title} for example was supposed to be in.

Comment: I've played around with "Scheduled reminders" and I can see a way to trigger what I need in a different way. Thank you

Comment: @ArisK Glad to hear it!  There is work [actively underway](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/emailapi/merge_requests/3) to provide a solution to the event token problem in CiviRules.